# Does adding LinkedIn button to a website result in cookies that track users?

Tags: cookie, linkedin

We are planning to add the LinkedIn button in our website. But the restriction we are having is, the website should not use the cookies which collect the personal information.
No impersonation.
But I read the LinkedIn website privacy policy, which says it uses both persistent and session cookie.

So i need some more inputs on this one - is LinkedIn website tracking the user's login information ??

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is LinkedIn website tracking the user's login information ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [LinkedIn Share Button](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-button) is available with or without count mode. If you select the no count mode and you host the button image on your server, there's no way for LinkedIn to track user sessions or get other user information from your website.

Otherwise (if you want to be paranoid), LinkedIn might actually know when a user requests a page on your site and get request details by inspecting the log of the requests sent to the script or the image.

Whether LinkedIn is actually doing this right now is something I don't know. You should read the LinkedIn TOS and Privacy Policy.